# Different gap width in Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, cross-browser

This is my HTML and CSS code

HTML

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchMain" runat="server" CssClass="text-box" />
<asp:ImageButton ID="imbSearchMain" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Resources/Images/icon-search.png" CssClass="custom-text-box-img" />
```

CSS

```
.text-box {
    border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
    padding: 4px;
    margin: 0;
    height: 16px;
}

.custom-text-box-img {
    border: 1px solid #CFCFCF;
    height: 18px;
    padding: 3px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    margin-left: -3px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Output of this code behaves differently on Chrome and IE

[image]

Output of chrome is as expected, while the IE has a different size gap between two controls.

How to fix this to behave similarly in different browsers?

Comment: A few options to try: 1. Float both elements and remove the negative left margin. 2. Remove the whitespace between the 2 ASP tags in the source code and remove the negative left margin. 3. Apply an explicit `font-size` to the parent container (might increase the chances of the gap width being the same in all browsers).

Comment: @MattCoughlin Applying a `font-size` to parent container fixed the issue :), Add your Comment as a Answer I'll accept it as Correct... Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options to try:

1. Float both elements and remove the negative left margin.
2. Remove the whitespace between the 2 ASP tags in the source code and remove the negative left margin.
3. Apply an explicit `font-size` to the parent container (might increase the chances of the gap width being the same in all browsers).